# Incorrect values when getting data from access to excel

Tags: excel, database, ms-access

I am making an excel report based in many queries from an access data base. I find that data from many queries is not being imported correctly.

When the query result is this:

[image]

In excel I am getting this data:

[image]

The query is the result of an If statement. Could it lead to the mistake?

Comment: I got a way to fix it. In the Excel Wizard, instead of Get External Data from data Base, I picked up "from other sources". Problem solved